# Is it true that, for every $w \in \mathbb{C}$, there is a function $f(z)$ such that $\oint_\mathcal{C} f(z) dz = w$?

Tags: complex-analysis

So we let $\mathcal{C}$ be the anticlockwise circle of radius 1 around 0. Is it true that, for every $w \in \mathbb{C}$, there is a function $f(z)$ such that $\oint_\mathcal{C} f(z) dz = w$?

Would a valid example be

$$f(z) = \frac{w}{z-a}$$

where $a$ is in the region enclosed by $\mathcal{C}$? Since we're just looking for *a* function..

Comment: Modulo some $2\pi i$ factors, yes that would work

Comment: Right, $f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\frac{w}{z}$ works - no reason to add $a$ in there. In general, if $f(z)=\sum_{n=-k}^{\infty} a_nz^n$ has radius of convergence greater than $1$ for $z\neq 0$, then $a_{-1}=\frac{w}{2\pi i}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews A radius of convergence is usually only defined for a power series.